# Publish document in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

Hi all from last couple of hour I am trying to publish a document and on which i am setting some custom data type value as I am saving serialized value : In umbraco data type value will be available in database and in umbraco.config file only after publishing document so In my custom document type I have a button called add user and I want to save it in db when this button is called for it I need to publish the document for that I am using :

```
//Get the document by it's ID
Document d = new Document(currentDocID);

//Mark it ready for publishing
d.Publish(new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));

//Tell the runtime to update the document cache
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(d.Id);

//call republishing from the api:
umbraco.library.RefreshContent();

//Server.ScriptTimeout = 100000;
//umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.RePublishAll();
//umbraco.library.RefreshContent();
```

But it's not able to change Umbraco.config file and data base file while If do by clicking on publish in umbraco data is saved in umbraco db as well as in config file. I am not able to figure it out do i missing something..

Comment: Could you edit you question to add some full stops/commas? It is difficult to understand what it is you are asking. Are you trying to set a document property programmatically? If so, this is missing from your code example.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample looks right for save a node programmatically, all that's missing is a line to update the field that's changed, which if it was aliased as 'myField' in the document type would meaning changing to:

```
var myValue = "[{ serialized value that might need escaping }]";

Document d = new Document(currentDocID);
d.getProperty("myField").Value = myValue;
d.Publish(new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(d.Id);
```